# CoreData compare two NSManagedObjects by their attributes and relationships

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have filter object. It has several attributes and relationships. I want to create new filter object if there's no one with the same attributes & relationships. How to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

I would choose a more general approach..
I would take the NSEntityDescriptions of the object and build a predicate with all properties in that Description.

so like..

```
- (void)insertIfUnique:(NSManagedObject*)obj inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)ctx {

NSMutableString *format = [NSMutableString string];

NSEntityDescription *desc = obj.entity;
NSArray *attrs = desc.attributeKeys;

for(NSString *attr in attrs) {
    if(format.length)
        [format appendString:@" AND "];
    [format appendFormat:@"%@==%@", attr, [obj valueForKey:attr]];
}

NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:format];
NSFetchRequest *f = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:desc.name];
f.predicate = p;
if([ctx countForFetchRequest:f error:nil]==0)
    [ctx insertObject:obj];

}
```

Comment: for relationships it could be done kinda similar but it gets crazy expensive :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually search CoreData for any existing filter objects. If not found, you can process to create a new filter:

Here is one helper function

```
+(id)uniqueEntityfForName:(NSString *)name 
                withValue:(id)value 
                   forKey:(NSString *)key
   inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];    
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:context];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[key stringByAppendingString:@" == %@"], value];
    NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    id entity = [result lastObject];
    if (entity == nil) {
        entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [entity setValue:value forKey:key];
    } else {
        entity = [result lastObject];
    }

    return entity;
}
```

I use this method like this:

```
SomeEntity *entity = [CDUtils uniqueEntityfForName:@"SomeEntity" withValue:@"foo" forKey:@"bar" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

You may have to define your own predicate.

Comment: My filter object has several attributes as well as relationships.. How to determine that two filters are equal? Equal for my situation is when all attributes and relationships are the same.

Comment: you can create a predicate with all your attributes `request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Key1 == %@ AND Key2 like %@", value1, value2];` this will get you one object if it already exist, or no one if the attributes differ