# isEqual for NSManagedObjects

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm creating a generic category to implement `isEqual` functionality for an `NSManagedObject`. As you can't override isEqual on managed objects i've called it `isExactlyTheSameAs`. I've using KVC to access any properties i have on the `NSManagedObjects` i want to test.

The problem i have is that while it works fine for simple classes with just properties. With a relationship it throws a "*is not key value coding-compliant for the key*" error when i use `valueForKey` to get the relationship.

Anyone know how to get this working for relationships too?

```
@implementation NSManagedObject (ExactlySame)

- (BOOL)isExactlyTheSameAs:(id)object
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        unsigned int count = 0;
        objc_property_t *props = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", property_getName(props[i])];
            id value1 = [self valueForKey:name];
            id value2 = [object valueForKey:name];
            if ([value1 isKindOfClass:[NSSet class]]) {
                for (id arrayValue1 in (NSSet *)value1) {
                    if ([arrayValue1 isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]]) {
                        for (id arrayValue2 in (NSSet *)value2) {
                            if (![arrayValue2 isExactlyTheSameAs:arrayValue1]) {
                                return NO;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if ([value1 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                if (![value1 isEqualToString:value2]) {
                    return NO;
                }
            } else if ([value1 isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
                if (![value1 isEqualToNumber:value2]) {
                    return NO;
                }
            }
            else if (value1 != value2) {
                return NO;
            }
        }
        return YES;
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [similar question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290317/coredata-compare-two-nsmanagedobjects-by-their-attributes-and-relationships), that deals with *property to property comparison* of managed objects.
The approach there uses NSManagedObject's `entityDescription` instead of property introspection.
You could use the description's `relationShipsByName` property to create a similar fetch request for your relationships.

In case you just want to test if an object is the same as one already existent in the persistent store, you could use the `objectID` property as described here:
[Should I use == or [NSManagedObject isEqual:] to compare managed objects in the same context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298005/should-i-use-or-nsmanagedobject-isequal-to-compare-managed-objects-in-the)